# Why Are Elements of Sidebar Hidden?

Tags: css, sidebar

[On this page](http://glamourunderground.com) you can see that elements of the sidebar are hidden by the content (as shown in pic below). This happened while I was editing the menu... Any idea what's going wrong here?

Thanks,

Tara[image]

Comment: Do you have a site we can go to to see it? Or perhaps dump it into a http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: You need to purchase your images.

Comment: @josh Yep, the site is linked under 'On this page' in the original question

Comment: @SLaks I know, I haven't finished developing the site yet. But I don't think that has anything to do with this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `width: 970px` from `.single`.

It's on line 795 inside `/wp-content/themes/primus/primus/style.css`.

---

In response to comment:

To do it your way, add `position: relative` to `#rightcol`. Disregard my previous fix.

Comment: @thrity But, I actually want the .single to be that width. Before the sidebar was on top of the .single and it looked much better.

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you @thirty - will accept as answer in 4 min.